# How can I display a real address on map using angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this function which displays a marker on my map. I would like to show my office address instead of the marker right on the map. How can I do this?

```
updateRideLocation(rl: RideLocation) {
    let centerRide = new google.maps.LatLng(Number(rl.current_latitude), Number(rl.current_longitude));
    if (this.markerRide) {
      this.markerRide.setPosition(centerRide);
    } else {
      this.markerRide = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: centerRide,
        map: this.maps.map,
        title: 'Ride is here!',
        icon: 'assets/imgs/map_car_mini.png'
      });
    }
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To plot points on a map using an address, you can use the Geocoding service. Documentation is here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Here is an example approach that you can tweak for your specific scenario:

```
var geocoder;
var map;

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  }

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>
  <div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
    <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </div>
</body>
```